# Scheduling logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch with Logstash. I am currently ingesting a CSV file and I want it to run by schedule. Is there a configuration for it like the "schedule" config when ingesting SQL that I could use with the same function?

> schedule => "* * * * *"

Comment: No there isn't, but you could use an external cron schedule for that.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#_scheduling

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [file input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_write_interval) in Logstash, there is an option called `stat_interval` ([link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-stat_interval)) which specifies how often in seconds the file is checked to see if it has been modified. Is there any reason you need it to run it at specific times?  If not, you could use something like...

```
input {
   file {
     path => [ "/tmp/your-file" ]
     stat_interval => 60
   }
}
filter {
   csv { }
}
```

This would check your file for changes every 60 seconds and parse the csv into key/value pairs.